# gradient cut from top to bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

This is a follow up question to - [gradient direction from left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350926/gradient-direction-from-left-to-right)

In this apple refection sample code,

[Apple Reflection Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reflection/Listings/MyViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008063-MyViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6)

when the size slider is moved, the image is cut from bottom to top. How can I cut it from top to bottom when the slider is moved? I am trying to understand this tutorial better

```
//I know the code is in this section here but I can't figure out what to change
- (UIImage *)reflectedImage:(UIImageView *)fromImage withHeight:(NSUInteger)height
{
...
}

    //it probably has something to do with this code. 
//I think this tells it how much to cut. 
//Though I can't figure out how does it know where the 0,0 of the image is and why 
// keep 0,0 of the image on the top? I am assuming this is where it hinges its 
//point and cuts the image from bottom to top
CGContextRef MyCreateBitmapContext(int pixelsWide, int pixelsHigh)
{

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // create the bitmap context
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, pixelsWide, pixelsHigh, 8, 0, colorSpace,(kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst));
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return bitmapContext;
}
```

[image]

What if the image to reflect was on the top. So in order to show it properly, I need to reveal it from top down, not bottom up. That;s the effect I am trying to achieve. In this case I just moved the UIImageViews around in their storyboard example. You now see my dilemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's very similar to @Putz1103 answer. You should create a new method starting from the previous - (UIImage *)reflectedImage:(UIImageView *)fromImage withWidth:(NSUInteger)width.

```
- (UIImage *)reflectedImage:(UIImageView *)fromImage withWidth:(NSUInteger)width andHeight:(NSUInteger)height
{
     ....
     CGContextClipToMask(mainViewContentContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height), gradientMaskImage);
     ....
}
```

Then in slideAction method, use something like:

```
self.reflectionView.image = [self reflectedImage:self.imageView withWidth:self.imageView.bounds.size.width andHeight:reflectionHeight];
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you again for helping me out. Unfortunately this doesn't work. If you notice the image's gradient is still at the bottom. What I am trying to do is make it flip the other way. Unfortunately the code you gave me doesn't do that. I mean I see no difference in behavior.

Comment: the Image I am trying to revel is on the top. see screenshot and some explanation in my post.

Comment: Luis - o you see the dark gradient on the top? And when you move the size slider then gradient remains on the top of the inverted image? I just cleaned and downloaded a fresh copy of this tutorial again, made the two changes that you had shown and I still see it behave the same way. Can you please post a picture of what you see?

Comment: @SamBudda I limited my answer to : "How can I cut it from top to bottom when the slider is moved?", and that is working for me. You also need to change the behavior of the Gradient?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be this line:

```
CGContextClipToMask(mainViewContentContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, fromImage.bounds.size.width, height), gradientMaskImage);
```

If you change it to this it should do the opposite:

```
CGContextClipToMask(mainViewContentContext, CGRectMake(0.0, fromImage.bounds.size.height - height, fromImage.bounds.size.width, height), gradientMaskImage);
```

Basically you need to set the clipping rectangle to the bottom of the image instead of the top of the image.  This will invert what your slider does, but that is easy to resolve and I'll leave that for your exercise.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't do it. Its still cutting from bottom to top